# JPA - Populate/Map Column in child Table with Parent Table Column

Tags: mysql, jpa, one-to-one

Table A - Table B Mapping goes below:
[image]

My requirement is to have client_id column in table B mapped and updated as the client_id column in table A.

Comment: So essentially, you have a db schema that violates 2NF and you want JPA to handle it properly? Why not normalize the schema instead (by either making `client_id` part of the primary key in `Table A`, or removing it altogether from `Table B`)?

Comment: @crizzis Am just trying to understand from a learning point of view that whether there is at-least some way to achieve this.